# Is it possible to obtain prediction at the end of epoch in Keras?

Tags: validation, keras, prediction

At the end of epoch, Keras prints validation loss and probably other metrics, like validation accuracy.

Doesn't this mean it was to compute predicions against validation set? Can I obtain results of this predicion?

At the end of epoch, I see field `validation_data` which probably contains concatenation of my `x` and `y` and also additional column of ones. What are they?

Comment: "At the end of epoch, I see field validation_data which probably contains concatenation of my x and y and also additional column of ones." Could you please clarify what do you mean by that? Your question is a bit vague. `validation_data` is an argument of `fit` method which you can pass your validation data and the model would be evaluated on it at the end of each epoch. So now what is your question exactly?

Comment: No, there is a member in a model class called `validation_data` too and it doesn't contain exactly what I sent as a parameter.